# SMS text counter in Android

Tags: android, sms

I want to implement SMS text counter like feature as in Android default messaging application. So that after each 161 character counter should be incremented by one and on deleting of character it should decrease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.floor(chars / 160) + 1`

This will divide the number of characters you have by the SMS-limit (160), cut off the decimal place and add "1".

http://www.java-examples.com/find-floor-value-number-using-math.floor

e.g. chars = 170, then (chars / 160) = 1,0625 and floor(1,0625) = 1, the result would be that 170 characters mean 2 SMS.

Comment: You don't need Math.floor, just use an int datatype. The decimals will be cut automatically by the system

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
int countSMS = (nbOfCharacters / 160) + 1;
```

Comment: That's modulo. So if nbOfCharacters = 170, your line would return 11.

Comment: Module returns just the remainder, not the SMS count.
Use int cnt = (nbOfCharacters / 160) + 1

Comment: @Select0r, saxos: thanks for the comments, I updated my answer.